# Alter layouts of specific words inside of text view

Tags: android, textview

I'm looking to be able to manipulate the text inside of a textview. Check the example image below for good explanation of what I'm looking to achieve. I'm assuming I'll probably be working with spannables, but I just have no idea where to start.

[image]

Basically I want to convert any word prefixed with *n* amount of carets to a word with *n* amount of padding under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
String rawHtml = "<p>Should <sup>I<sup>eat<sup>cake?</sup></sup></sup>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(rawHtml));
```

[image]

Sample project: https://github.com/raiytu4/stackcase003